# when i post/get/put a request in thunder client should i run my server.js file in backend to test these API's or not?

Tags: node.js, thunderclient

but beside this i also try to run my server but got an error that are  following below :

before this error i also reinstall nodejs but cant find anything to solve this error,

i am a beginner somebody help me.

```
C:\Users\faaaast\Desktop\Projectform\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:211
        throw new Error(msg);
              ^

Error: Route.put() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as put] (C:\Users\faaaast\Desktop\Projectform\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:211:15)
    at file:///C:/Users/faaaast/Desktop/Projectform/server/router/route.js:28:30
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)
```

i am trying to test post/get API's in thunder client but can't run server before that.